# For Each through single rank of multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, foreach, vba

I have a 2D array - aArray(1,variable) and want to know how I can **For Each** through the first rank of the array, ie only read aArray(0 , variable)

This is more for self educational purposes as to how if possible it can be done. I can do it with a for loop:

```
Dim a As Integer: For a = 0 to ?
  Range("A1").Value = aArray(0,a)
Next a
```

But was interested in using the For Each loop. So far I've got

```
Dim a As Variant: For Each S In aArray
  Range("A1").Value = S
Next a
```

But it iterates through all the array (0,0) (1,0) (0,1) (1,1) Etc...

Comment: You can't. You'd have to output the first rank into a new array. Why would you want to use `For Each` anyway?

Comment: No real reason other than learning about if its possible of not. Have gotten use to using For Each rather than loops when using large ranges in excel because its faster. Cheers for the answer.

Comment: `For Each` is faster with Collections but not with arrays.

Comment: See [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/129931) This supports what @Rory mentioned. Rory, you may want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You'd have to output the first rank into a new array, and then iterate through that.

There's no good reason to use `For Each` anyway since it's slower - see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/129931